# Define agent population which is dispersed in specific areas or divided in groups?

Tags: anylogic

I have one agent (100 population) in main. Is it possible to divide this population into several groups, separated from each other but still connected?
There was a solution where we can define this population in another agent (containing square fields), but we need not have this dependency over another agent. I hope there will be a solution.
Thank you for help.

Answer (score 0):

Sure. Many different options, depends on what you want to do with them.

Easiest is to use a parameter within your Agent type, maybe "gender". Create an OptionList "availableGenders" with entries like "FEMALE" and "MALE".

Then, when creating your agents, you can assign each a gender via that parameter.

Now, you have 1 population of humans but you can easily filter them by gender (using `findAll(myPopulation, a -> a.gender.equals(MALE))` or similar)

Lots of example models use this approach, please check them to understand how it is done.